# Drawing erases after while loop in Java paint method

Tags: java, swing, paint

I'm working on a little program to draw stacking cups using a paint method controlled by nested loops. I have everything working, except that when the outer While loops finishes, the drawing erases.

The program consists of two While loops. The first is for incrementing the row of the drawing and the second draws the cups in the row.

Watching the program in Debug mode, after the final execution of the outer While loop, the outer While statement is evaluated (while (baseLength > 0) as false, then the program goes up a line to int counter2 = 0, the drawing disappears and the program exits.

I also tried building this with For loops instead of While, and I get the same effect. Once the outer loop is evaluated as false, the drawing disappears.

It seems that the paint(g) method does something I don't quite understand that's causing the drawing to erase. Any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Cups1 extends JFrame {

    /*
     * Declaring instance variables. startX and startY represent the top left coordinates
     * of the first cup block in the bottom row. cupWidth and cupHeight represent the width
     * and height of each row.
     */
    int startX, startY, cupWidth, cupHeight;
    int baseLength; //number of cups in bottom row
    int cupSpacing; //spacing between adjacent cups

        //Constructor calls constructor from JFrame class, argument is window title
        public Cups1()
        {
        super("Example");
        startX = 100;
        startY = 300;
        cupWidth = 25;
        cupHeight = 40;
        baseLength = 7;
        cupSpacing = 6;
        }

        //Paint method fills pattern from bottom to top
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            //Call paint method of JFrame
            super.paint(g);
            //startX and startY are variables to set original point of reference
            //drawX and drawY are local variables for each cup instance
            int drawY = startY, drawX = startX;
            int counter1 = 0;
            while (baseLength > 0)
            {
                int counter2 = 0;
                //Control number of cups in level 
                while (baseLength > counter2) 
                {

                    //Make odd levels red and even levels blue to alternate colors
                    if (baseLength % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                    }

                    //Draw cup shapes   
                g.fillRect(drawX, drawY, cupWidth, cupHeight);
                drawX = drawX + cupWidth + cupSpacing;
                counter2++;
                }
            //Decrement base length to reduce number of cups on next level   
            baseLength--;

            counter1++;
            //Shift x by 1/2 of the total value of cupWidth and cupSpacing
            drawX = startX + (((cupWidth + cupSpacing)/2) * counter1);
            //Raise height of next level by one cup height
            drawY = startY - (cupHeight * counter1);   
            }       
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Create application object with 550 x 550 size and visibility = true
            Cups1 cup = new Cups1();
            cup.setSize(550,550);
            cup.setVisible(true);
            //Close application by clicking "x"
            cup.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

}
```

Comment: `JFrame` is designed to be a container instead of a canvas. Try make `Cups1` a subclass of `JComponent`, do the painting logic there, then add it to a standard `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing components are continually being repainted whenever Swing determines the components should be painted.

The first thing the component does when it is painted is clear its own background and then the painting is redone.

Therefore variables always need to be reset to the starting value (within the painting method) so loops can execute correctly. For example, in your case the "baseLength" variable wound need to be set to "7" in the painting method, otherwise the first time the method is called is it set to 0, so therefore there is never any need to do the painting again.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.